# How can I plot charts in excel at a predefined location, everytime I run a macro to plot the charts?

Tags: excel, vba, charts, excel-charts

I need to plot charts at a predefined position in my worksheet when I run the macro to plot the charts. The problem is that the charts are automatically plotted in a weird manner and I don't like that. I want to make sure I can predefine the exact positions at which I want the charts to be plotted on running the macro. I have attached 2 images here, 1 image shows how it's currently plotted and the other shows how I want the charts to be plotted. Any kind of help would be highly appreciated.

This is how I want the charts to be shown on the sheet:
[image: This is how I want the charts to be shown on the sheet]

This is how it's currently showing up, with one pie chart overlapping the other and the line chart obscuring the macro buttons as well
[image: This is how it's currently showing up, with one pie chart overlapping the other and the line chart obscuring the macro buttons as well]

This is the code I used, starting with the line chart, followed by the pie charts. I'm new to VBA and coding so please excuse the code structure.

```
' CHART Code

Dim chart As chart

Dim k As Integer
Dim p As Integer
Dim j As Integer

Dim arrDEM() As Long

Dim arrDATE() As Integer

ReDim arrDEM(1 To 65) As Long

ReDim arrDATE(1 To 65) As Integer


            Dim DEM As Integer

            j = findcell.Select

            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select

             For DEM = 1 To 65
             arrDEM(DEM) = ActiveCell.Value
             ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select

             Next DEM


             Debug.Print arrDEM(65)


             Range("B1").Activate

            For p = 1 To 65


            arrDATE(p) = ActiveCell.Value


            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
            Next p


            Debug.Print arrDATE(65)


            Range("B31:B031") = arrDEM

            Range("B31:B031").Select


Set cht1 = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=200, Width:=4500, Top:=200, Height:=4000)

ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
Set chart = ActiveChart
chart.ChartType = 4





chart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = x
chart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = arrDATE
chart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = arrDEM





 With ActiveChart

  'chart name
 .HasTitle = True
 .ChartTitle.Characters.Text = "Demand Distribution"


 'X axis name
 .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
 .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Weeks"
    'y-axis name
 .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
 .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Demand"





 'Copy chart from Original file
  ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy

 'Paste chart in destination file
   Worksheets("Model Calculations").Paste

  'Deleting Charts
Worksheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects.Delete


  'Activating destination chart
   Worksheets("Model Calculations").Activate

 Application.DisplayAlerts = False
End With

' PieC Macro

Range("C10:D11").Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(262, xl3DPie).Select
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'Model Calculations'!$C$10:$D$11")

With ActiveChart

  'chart name
 .HasTitle = True
 .ChartTitle.Characters.Text = "Continuous Review"
 '  .Name = "Continuous Chart"


 End With



 '    PieP Macro
 '


Range("C10,D10,C12,D12").Select

ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(262, xl3DPie).Select
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'Model Calculations'!$C$10,'Model Calculations'!$D$10,'Model Calculations'!$C$12,'Model Calculations'!$D$12")



With ActiveChart

  'chart name
 .HasTitle = True
 .ChartTitle.Characters.Text = "Periodic Review"
 '.Name = "Periodic Chart"
 End With


End Sub
```

Comment: Use a template with the charts already defined then use the macro to paste the fresh data into the relevant ranges.

Comment: I tried recording a macro to see how the code actually works and then tried to make changes to the code as per my requirement. But the problem is that everytime I plot a new chart, the chart name changes due to which my macro is failing and I'm unable to get the output. Is there a way to write the code in a way such that the macro works for any chart number?

Comment: Did you consider trying what I suggested?

Answer (score 0):

Your code could use some help in a number of ways. To answer your question, I'll ignore all that, and fix one piece of code. Here is what I'm replacing:

```
' PieC Macro

Range("C10:D11").Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(262, xl3DPie).Select
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'Model Calculations'!$C$10:$D$11")

With ActiveChart
  'chart name
  .HasTitle = True
  .ChartTitle.Characters.Text = "Continuous Review"
  '  .Name = "Continuous Chart"
End With
```

I'll start by declaring and assigning a few variables, then create, populate, and position a chart.

```
Dim WkSht As Worksheet
Set WkSht = Worksheets("Model Calculations")
WkSht.Activate

Dim rChartData As Range
Set rChartData = WkSht.Range("C10:D11")

Dim rChartCover As Range
Set rChartCover = WkSht.Range("F10:K18")

Dim NewChart As Chart
Set NewChart = WkSht.Shapes.AddChart2(262, xl3DPie).Chart

With NewChart
  .SetSourceData rChartData

  With .Parent
    .Left = rChartCover.Left
    .Top = rChartCover.Top
    .Width = rChartCover.Width
    .Height = rChartCover.Height
  End With
End With
```

You could replace this:

```
Set WkSht = Worksheets("Model Calculations")
WkSht.Activate
```

with this:

```
Set WkSht = ActiveSheet
```

to make it more general, and if you know the position and size of the resulting chart, you can plug those in instead of using the position and size of a given range (like I used `rChartCover` above).